# Changing filenames in Ruby when all files have no type?

Tags: ruby

I have a directory filled with 5 files with no filetype (perhaps their filetype is '.txt' - I am uncertain), named "file1", "file2"...

I am trying to convert them to CSV format with the following code:

```
require('fileutils')
folder_path = "correct_folder_path"
Dir.foreach(folder_path) do |f|
  next if f == '.' || f == '..'
  #confirm inputs are correct (they are)
  #p f
  #p f+".csv" 
  File.rename(f, f+".csv")
end
```

I have p'd out f to confirm everything is working, but the line

```
File.rename(f,f+".csv")
```

is throwing the error: "in `rename': No such file or directory... (Errno::ENOENT)"

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## With Dir and File

You could change the directory to `folder_path`. If some files might have '.txt' extension, you need to remove the extension first in order not to get a `.txt.csv` file :

```
folder_path = "correct_folder_path"
Dir.chdir(folder_path) do
  Dir.foreach(".") do |f|
    next if File.directory?(f)
    basename = File.basename(f, '.*')
    new_file = basename + '.csv'
    p f
    p new_file
    ## Uncomment when you're sure f and new_file are correct :
    # File.rename(f, new_file) unless f == new_file
  end
end
```

## With Pathname

With [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-rename), it's usually much easier to filter and rename files :

```
require 'pathname'
folder_path = "correct_folder_path"

Pathname.new(folder_path).children.each do |f|
  next if f.directory?
  p f
  p f.sub_ext('.csv')
  ## Uncomment if you're sure f and subext are correct :
  # f.rename(f.sub_ext('.csv'))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The paths returned by `Dir.foreach` are relative to the `folder_path` that you passed in.  Your call to `File.rename` tries to rename a file in the current working directory, which is probably not the same directory as that specified by `folder_path`.

You can make the rename succeed by prepending `folder_path` to the filename:

```
f = File.join(folder_path, f)
File.rename(f, f + ".csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative:

```
require 'pathname'

folder.children.each do |child|
  # Other logic here
  child.rename(child.dirname + (child.basename.to_s + '.csv'))
end
```